# How to use BorderBehavior with ajax rerendering

Tags: java, wicket

I want to use a BorderBehavior to add additional markup around different components.

```
MyBorderBehavior extends BorderBehavior {

}

<wicket:border>
<div class="myBorderBehavior">
    <wicket:body />
    <!-- some more HTML code -->
</div>
</wicket:border>
```

So at some point, I add a new MyBorderBehavior to a component.

```
MyComponent myComponent = new MyComponent().add(new MyBorderBehavior());
```

But when I want to refresh myComponent via ajax

```
ajaxRequestTarget.add(myComponent)
```

The Html markup of MyBorderBehavior is drawn again without removing the already existing markup of MyBorderBehavior in the dom. As a result, the markup of MyBorderBehavior is shown twice or more often in the browser.

How can I add a border to a component which can be re-rendered with ajax?

A working solution I found so far is to remove the markup of MyBorderbehavior manually via JavaScript:

```
MyBorderBehavior extends BorderBehavior {
    @Override
    public void onComponentTag(Component component, ComponentTag tag) {
        super.onComponentTag(component, tag);

        IValueMap attributes = tag.getAttributes();
        attributes.put("class", attributes.getString("class", "") + " hasMyBorderbehavior");
    }
}

Wicket.Event.subscribe('/dom/node/removing', function(a, attributes, c, d, e) {
    var component = $('#' + attributes['id']);
    if (component.hasClass("hasMyBorderbehavior"))
    {
        component.closest(".myBorderBehavior").replaceWith(component);
    }
});
```

But this seems to be very hacky.

There are three cases I found so far which are relevant for me:

1. The component with the BorderBehavior is rerendered via ajax
2. A parent component of the component with the BorderBehavior is rerendered via ajax
3. The whole page is rerendered

Answer (score 1):

You can make your Behavior [temporary](https://github.com/apache/wicket/blob/7cfa536d687a181d73bc2e38d1e7ffc3e0032f0e/wicket-core/src/main/java/org/apache/wicket/behavior/Behavior.java#L199) and this will overcome the problem when re-painting with Ajax, but might break it when re-rendering the whole page.

A better solution probably is to override `beforeRender` of BorderBehavior and do nothing when this is an Ajax request:

```
@Override public void beforeRender(Component component) {
  if (!RequestCycle.get().find(AjaxRequestTarget.class).isPresent()) {
     super.beforeRender(component);
  }
}
```

Same for `afterRender()`.

The code above is for Wicket 8.x where `RequestCycle.get().find(Class<T>)` returns `Optional<T>`. If you use older version then you need to check for `null` instead: `if (RequestCycle.get().find(AjaxRequestTarget.class) != null)`

Comment: Good try but your solution sadly fails in case 2. Therefore I will have to stick to my current solution as it works in all cases although it uses JavaScript. But good Idea with the temporary Behavior, I did not know that feature.

Comment: Fails how ? Is there an error or what exactly happens ?

Comment: Well, if the parent is re-rendered via Ajax, all the current HTML content of it in the browser is removed. As a result, the HTML of our border will be removed. In your code, we will not re-render the border, as it is done via ajax. As a result, the border will be gone.

Comment: I understand. I see another approach by using `AjaxRequestTarget.Listener` but it will be much more complex than your JS solution, so better stay with it.

Comment: You are right. I wonder why wicket does not provide a out of the box solution here? Or some warning would be nice :)